# How do I force-quit the program?

Tags: cipher, pattern, lateral-thinking, knowledge

My friend has been playing with a program he found. He enters a 5-digit number into the command line and receives another 5-digit number in return. However, after 20 or so entries, he's about done and ready to quit. Unfortunately, there doesn't appear to be a "Quit" or "Exit" button anywhere in sight. These are his inputs and the program's responses thus far:

```
> 32908
Response: 32837
> 30351
Response: 32910
> 32872
Response: 32872
> 30280
Response: 30354
> 30278
Response: 32874
> 14727
Response: 30246
> 30246
Response: 32838
> 31992
Response: 14767
> 32799
Response: 31992
> 14654
Response: 30283
> 32944
Response: 14802
> 32909
Response: 32909
> 30316
Response: 32944
> 30354
Response: 30354
> 35536
Response: 35504
> 35538
Response: 32946
> 34276
Response: 26468
> 14619
Response: 35503
> 14875
Response: 34098
> 26533
Response: 26432
> ?????
```

---

Being a Linux expert, I know that every command-line program like this has a force-quit option, but I can't figure out how the program works. What should I tell my friend to type in place of the question marks in order to quit the program?

---

I'll add some clarification points to make this puzzle a bit more clear, since it (not surprisingly) has been causing some confusion!

- The story is mostly flavor, so I wouldn't stress too much over it. What you need to know are the entries and responses of the program, and the fact that my friend is trying to 'force-quit' it, whatever that might entail.
- A non-5 digit number *probably* would end up being an invalid input, though I might have to check that to be sure. Either way, that's not the solution to the puzzle. There is a valid input that will force the program to quit.
- This puzzle will require some knowledge that deems it unsolvable to a subset of the puzzlers on this site. If you're working hard on it and get stopped at that point, I encourage you to post a partial answer so that you can at least get some upvotes!
- The title may be confusing, but I promise that when the solution is revealed it will make perfect sense.
- There is a logical answer to this puzzle, but figuring out how to get there will involve some lateral thinking. I'm fixing the tags around right now and will add a related hint.

Hopefully this specifies everything for you. If you're still confused (which I wouldn't blame you for), here's a hint as well!

**Hint 1:**

> The order in which you'll need to use the tags is: [cryptograms](/questions/tagged/cryptograms), [lateral-thinking](/questions/tagged/lateral-thinking), [trivia](/questions/tagged/trivia), [pattern](/questions/tagged/pattern). This could definitely be considered open to interpretation, but if you start with [cryptograms](/questions/tagged/cryptograms) you'll be on the right track.

**Hint 2:**

> There hasn't been much headway on this, so I might have made it a bit too cryptic... time will tell. Anyhow, it should at least be apparent that the 5-digit numbers do not represent actual 5-digit numbers. Try decrypting them in some fashion and see if the result looks like anything you've seen before. Even if it doesn't, posting your results might help other people get to the bottom of it. The encryption method used is not a difficult one.

**Hint 3:**

> The given numbers are base 10. What do they look like in other bases?

**Hint 4 (a biggish one):**

> My friend is playing some kind of game with the computer.

Comment: Maybe he should just type `abort`.

Comment: He tried all of these. The program refuses to quit without proper input. :(

Comment: `CTRL-D`? `CTRL-C`? Is this a real program, or a program made up for the puzzle? I have a hard time believing that none of these exit the program.

Comment: This is a totally made-up program in a totally made-up situation. I'm sure in a real program unplugging the computer would suffice to shut it down.

Comment: @BaileyM: Was hoping you'd stick to your guns and insist that the computer was unplugged all along! _Cue spooky music_

Comment: can't he just type in a non-5 digit number and be done with it?

Comment: I'm theorizing that there is a mathematical/logical process that, when given the right input, will result in an illegal operation (divide by zero, for instance), thus crashing the program.

Comment: Is any knowledge of computers necessary to solve this puzzle? Also, how about the [pattern] tag?

Comment: @randal'thor: Thanks! :D there will be some specific knowledge necessary to solve this puzzle, but not of computers.

Comment: @Bailey M What's the use of [lateral thinking] tag. Isn't there a logical answer?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that nobody managed to crack the first part (the encryption). If you decide to give another hint later, I strongly suggest to address that part of the puzzle.

Comment: can i get the outputs for the number 11111,22222,33333,44444,55555,66666,77777,88888,99999,00000. As i can tell my friend to give these outputs for help.

Comment: What a brilliant idea for a puzzle!

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Expressing the numbers in

> base 36

and

> mapping the digits `10` through `35` to the letters `A`-`Z`

results in the following:

> [image]

In a more traditional format:

> `1.  e4    c5`
>  `2. Nf3    e6`
>  `3.  d4   cxd4`
>  `4. Nxd4  Nf6`
>  `5. Nd2    d6`
>  `6. Bd3   Nc6`
>  `7. Nxc6  bxc6`
>  `8. O-O   Be7`
>  `9.  b3   O-O`
>  `10. Bb2   Nd7`
>  `11.  f4   Bf6`
>  `12.  e5   dxe5`
>  `13. Ne4   exf4`
>  `14. Nxf6+ Nxf6`
>  `15. Rxf4  Re8`
>  `16. Rxf6  gxf6`
>  `17. Qg4+  Kf8`
>  `18. Ba3+  Re7`
>  `19. Bxh7  Qb6+?`
>  `20. Kh1   Ke8`

It looks like your friend is

> playing chess with the computer.

and needs to input

> A move that checkmates the computer.

You can inspect the current state of the game [here](http://analysis.cpuchess.com/?fen=r1b1k3%2Fp3rp1B%2F1qp1pp2%2F8%2F6Q1%2FBP6%2FP1P3PP%2FR6K%20w%20-%20-%203%2021&lmove=Ke8).  It looks like our best move is

> `21. Rd1`

Which forces

> `21. ...  Qd4`
>  `22. Rxd4  e5`
>  `23. Qg8#`

Converting back to numbers, the sequence is:

> `> 35461`
>  `response: 34168`
>  `> 35464`
>  `response: 32909`
>  `> 34280`
>  `bailey@puzzling~/chess$ _`

Comment: You're correct that my friend needs to input a game config unwinnable by the computer, but you've gone the wrong direction in terms of base conversion.

Comment: @Bailey Thanks for the hint... now I see why *cryptograms* makes sense.

Comment: No problem! I realize I might have made this puzzle too difficult, but I'm eager for it to be solved because I rather like the solution. :) Hopefully I can help someone get there soon. EDIT: Hey, looks like you made the first jump! Well done.

Comment: The values give perfect 4 digit numbers in Hex, which leads me to believe that's the right number base. I don't think chess can be interpreted this way though.
> 808c
8045
768f
808e
8068
8068
7648
7692
7646
806a
3987
7626
7626
8046
7cf8
39af
801f
7cf8
393e
764b
80b0
39d2
808d
808d
766c
80b0
7692
7692
8ad0
8ab0
8ad2
80b2
85e4
6764
391b
8aaf
3a1b
8532
67a5
6740

Comment: @Gettn You may want to read up on [standard notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_chess_notation) and look at my answer again.

Comment: Perfect. The answer I was looking for is '35461', because it puts the opponent in an unwinnable position. The rest of the game is relatively unnecessary, but I can't fault you for providing it as well. Well done!

Comment: @Bailey It only puts Black in an unwinnable position *if* White doesn't make any more mistakes, and we've certainly seen that mistakes are possible!  Not knowing the implementation details, I felt it safest to provide the whole game =)

Answer (score 28):

Try:

> 44444

Because

> Fours quit the program

Comment: Nice bit of wordplay! But it seems way too simple, and also doesn't justify the use of all those tags.

Comment: +1 for the humor although I agree it's unlikely to be the solution unless OP has created quite the school of red herrings.

Comment: +1 for a clever answer, but I promise I haven't included any crazy red herrings. :)

Answer (score 9):

I think that you should tell to him to try:

> 26432

Because:

> All of the digits converted to hexadecimal are of type int16 (16 bits long, a.k.a unicode characters) and those characters are in the range of chinese and japanese characters, so every character have a meaning, like the last response of the program that is the unicode character "26432" (U+6740, 杀) that means "kill".

pd: I have used the [Google Traductor](https://translate.google.com/#zh-CN/en/%E6%9D%80)

Comment: WOW! That's really cool and not at all what I intended, but you're on the right track, I promise. :)

Answer (score 9):

@2012rcampion is definitely on the right track. In fact, the winning move is:

> 21. Rd1 (as white)

The game is actually a recorded game between

> Viacheslav Ragozin vs P Noskov

Here's a link to the game:

> http://www.chessgames.com/perl/chessgame?gid=1282608

Again, full credit should go to @2012rcampion. I'm just a chess enthusiast doing some research :D

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling!

Comment: 2012rcampion gets the correct answer badge for his work plus providing the correct answer as well, but +1 for linking to the exact game I was referencing! Welcome to puzzling as well :)

Answer (score 2):

Try:

> Ctrl + C

Because:

> that force-quits a program in Mac, Linux and Windows ;)

Comment: You obviously haven't been reading the comments underneath the question. This computer's been possessed, and the program won't quit, even if you pull out the plug.